# How to delete a product that belongs to a category when its order is completed in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, woocommerce

I need to figure out how to delete a product(s) from a particular category when the order associated to it is completed (marked as completed) in WooCommerce.

Below is how the product is setup. users are allowed to create a product from frontend and when the product/products are created, it is assigned to a specific category. After purchase by user, an order is assigned to the product(s).

Now i want to be able to delete the product automatically when the order assigned to the product(s) is completed.

I have checked this question ([How Can I remove a particular product from an completed order in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212271/how-can-i-remove-a-particular-product-from-an-completed-order-in-woocommerce)) but doesn't help me, as well as this question ([Add Woocommerce Temporary product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281286/add-woocommerce-temporary-product))

Below is the HTML Code for the front end form

```
<form id="co_form" method="post" action="#" class="" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_currency"><?php _e('Select Currency', 'izzycart-function-code'); ?></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="co_currency" name="co_currency">
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="RMB">RMB</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="is_phone" class="form-group">
        <label class="disInBlk" for="co_isPhone"><?php _e('Is this order a Phone item?','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="co_isPhone" id="co-isPhone" <?php echo (isset($_POST['co_isPhone'])?'checked="checked"':'') ?>>
    </div>
    <div id="is_amazon" class="form-group">
        <label class="disInBlk" for="co_isAmazon"><?php _e('Is this an Amazon Product?','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="co_isAmazon" id="co-isAmazon" <?php echo (isset($_POST['co_isAmazon'])?'checked="checked"':'') ?>>
    </div>
    <div id="is_express" class="form-group no_express">
        <label class="disInBlk" for="co_isExpress"><?php _e('Express Delivery?','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="co_isExpress" id="co-isExpress" <?php echo (isset($_POST['co_isExpress'])?'checked="checked"':'') ?>>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productTitle"><?php _e('Product Name/Title','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="co_productTitle" class="form-control" id="co-productTitle">
        <div id="pt_error" class="co-error no"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productLink"><?php _e('Product URL','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="co_productLink" class="form-control" id="co-productLink"  placeholder="<?php _e('http://...', 'izzycart-function-code'); ?>">
        <div id="pl_error" class="co-error no"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productPriceUSD"><?php _e('Product Price (USD)','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="number" name="co_productPriceUSD" class="form-control" id="co-productPriceUSD"  step="0.01">
        <div id="pp_error" class="co-error no"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productShippingFee"><?php _e('Shipping Fee of Product/Item','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <div class="co-desc"><?php echo __('N.B: If the product is FREE shipping from the store you\'re buying from, enter 0 as the shipping fee.', 'izzycart-function-code'); ?></div>
        <input type="number" name="co_productShippingFee" class="form-control" id="co_productShippingFee" step="0.01">
        <div id="ps_error" class="co-error no"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productPriceNGN"><?php _e('Product Price Converted to NGN','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="number" name="co_productPriceNGN" class="form-control" id="co-productPriceNGN" readonly>
    </div>
    <div id="co_dWeight" class="form-group">
        <label for="co_productWeightKG"><?php _e('Weight (in KG)','izzycart-function-code').':'; ?></label>
        <input type="number" name="co_productWeightKG" class="form-control" id="co-productWeightKG"  step="0.001">
        <div id="pw_error" class="co-error no"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="co_submit" class="form-control" id="co-submit" value="<?php echo _e('Place Your Order', 'izzycart-function-code'); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="amountNGNUpdated" value="<?php echo $ExhangeRateUSD; ?>" id="CurrencyEX">
        <input type="hidden" id="currentCOUser" name="currentCOUser" value="<?php echo $usersID; ?>"> <!--$userID Gets the User ID. e.g 1 for administrator-->
    </div>
    <div class="response">
        <div id="spinner" class="spin"><span id="is_loading" class="loading"></span></div>
        <div id="co_success" class="co-success no"></div>
        <div id="co_error" class="co-error-call no"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and Below is the jQuery Code which is used to validate the form and send the data via Ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
$('#co_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.fielderr').removeClass('fielderr');
    $('#pt_error, #co_error').addClass('no');
    $('#pl_error, #co_error').addClass('no');
    $('#pp_error, #co_error').addClass('no');
    $('#ps_error, #co_error').addClass('no');
    $('#pw_error, #co_error').addClass('no');


    var coFormItself = $(this),
        userProductTitle = coFormItself.find('#co-productTitle').val(),
        userProductURL = coFormItself.find('#co-productLink').val(),
        userProductPrice = coFormItself.find('#co-productPriceUSD').val(),
        userShippingPrice = coFormItself.find('#co_productShippingFee').val(),
        userProductWeightS = userProductWeight = coFormItself.find('#co-productWeightKG').val(),
        productCategory = coFormItself.find('#productCategoryUpdate').val(),
        userWhoSubmittedForm = coFormItself.find('#currentCOUser').val(),
        is_PhoneProduct = coFormItself.find("#co-isPhone").prop("checked") ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        is_AmazonProduct = coFormItself.find("#co-isAmazon").prop("checked") ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        is_ExpressDelivery = coFormItself.find("#co-isExpress").prop("checked") ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        productCurrency = coFormItself.find('#co_currency').val(),
        ajaxurl = coFormItself.data('url');


        //Validate Product Title
        if(userProductTitle === '') {
            $('#co-productTitle').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pt_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pt_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pt_error').text('This field is required');
                $('#co_error').text('Product title field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        //Validate Product URL
        if(userProductURL === '') {
            $('#co-productLink').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pl_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pl_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pl_error').text('This field is required');
                $('#co_error').text('Product URL field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        if ( userProductURL && !userProductURL.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/) ) {
            $('#co-productLink').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pl_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pl_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pl_error').text('Please enter a valid URL. URL must contain http:// or https://');
                $('#co_error').text('Product URL field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        if ( is_AmazonProduct == 'Yes' && (userProductURL.toLowerCase().indexOf("amazon.com") == -1) ) {
            $('#co-productLink').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pl_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pl_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pl_error').text('This is not an Amazon product. Please enter a valid amazon product link.');
                $('#co_error').text('Product URL field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        //Validate Product Price
        if(userProductPrice === '' || userProductPrice == 0 ) {
            $('#co-productPriceUSD').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pp_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pp_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pp_error').text('This field is required');
                $('#co_error').text('Product price field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }else if ( userProductPrice < 0 ) {
            $('#co-productPriceUSD').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#pp_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#pp_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#pp_error').text('Product Price cannot be a negative value. Kindly enter a valid product price');
                $('#co_error').text('Product price field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        //Validate Product Shiiping Price
        if(userShippingPrice === '' ) {
            $('#co_productShippingFee').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#ps_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#ps_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#ps_error').text('This field is required');
                $('#co_error').text('Product shipping price field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }else if ( userShippingPrice < 0 ) {
            $('#co_productShippingFee').addClass('fielderr');
            if ( $('#ps_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                $('#ps_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                $('#ps_error').text('Product Price cannot be a negative value. Kindly enter a valid product price');
                $('#co_error').text('Product shipping price field is incorrect');
            }
            return
        }

        //Validate Product weight
        if( ( productCurrency == 'USD' || productCurrency == 'RMB' )  && is_PhoneProduct == 'No')  {
            if (userProductWeight === '') {
                $('#co-productWeightKG').addClass('fielderr');
                if ( $('#pw_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                    $('#pw_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                    $('#pw_error').text('This field is required');
                    $('#co_error').text('Product weight field is incorrect');
                }
                return
            }else if (productCurrency == 'USD' && is_PhoneProduct == 'No' && userProductWeight < 0.5 ) {
                $('#co-productWeightKG').addClass('fielderr');
                if ( $('#pw_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                    $('#pw_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                    $('#pw_error').text('The minimum weight is 0.5KG for USA Products/items.');
                    $('#co_error').text('Product weight field is incorrect');
                }
                return
            }else if (productCurrency == 'RMB' && is_PhoneProduct == 'No' && is_ExpressDelivery == 'Yes' && userProductWeight < 5 ) {
                $('#co-productWeightKG').addClass('fielderr');
                if ( $('#pw_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                    $('#pw_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                    $('#pw_error').text('The minimum weight is 5KG for China Products/items.');
                    $('#co_error').text('Product weight field is incorrect');
                }
                return
            }else if (productCurrency == 'RMB' && is_PhoneProduct == 'No' && is_ExpressDelivery == 'No' && userProductWeight < 5 ) {
                $('#co-productWeightKG').addClass('fielderr');
                if ( $('#pw_error, #co_error').hasClass('no') ) {
                    $('#pw_error, #co_error').removeClass('no');
                    $('#pw_error').text('The minimum weight is 5KG for China Products/items.');
                    $('#co_error').text('Product weight field is incorrect');
                }
                return
            }

        }

        if( ( productCurrency == 'USD' || productCurrency == 'RMB' )  && is_PhoneProduct == 'Yes')  {
            if (userProductWeight === '' || userProductWeight == 0 ) {
                var userProductWeightS = '1';
            }
        }


        $('#co-submit').val('Please Wait...');
        $('#co-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#co_currency').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#co_form :input").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#spinner").addClass('processing');


        $.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            productTitle    : userProductTitle, 
            productURL      : userProductURL, 
            productPrice    : userProductPrice, 
            shippingPrice   : userShippingPrice, 
            productWeight   : userProductWeightS, 
            coCurrency      : productCurrency, 
            productCategory : productCategory, 
            userID          : userWhoSubmittedForm, 
            is_Phone        : is_PhoneProduct, 
            is_Amazon       : is_AmazonProduct, 
            is_Express      : is_ExpressDelivery, 
            action : 'customOrder_Send_the_Order'
        },

        error : function( response ){

        },
        success : function( response ){
            if ( response > 1 ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#co-submit').val('Place Your Order');
                    $('#co-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#co_currency').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("#co_form :input").prop("disabled", false);
                    $(':input','#co_form')
                      .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, #co_currency')
                      .val('')
                      .prop('checked', false);
                    $("#spinner").removeClass('processing');
                    if ( $('#co_dWeight, #is_express').hasClass('no_weight') ) {
                        $('#co_dWeight, #is_express').removeClass('no_weight');
                    }

                    if ( $('#co_success').hasClass('no') ) {
                        $('#co_success').removeClass('no');
                        $('#co_success').text('Your Custom Order has been created and added to cart. You\'d be redirect to cart now to complete your order.');
                    }

                }, 500);
            }

        }

    });

});
});
```

I used Ajax on the form to create the order and when i added the code in the above questions like this;

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_customOrder_Send_the_Order', 'CustomOrder_Details_Callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_customOrder_Send_the_Order', 'CustomOrder_Details_Callback' );
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'CustomOrder_Details_Callback')

function CustomOrder_Details_Callback( $order_id ) {
    //Get All Value from Ajax
    $pTitle         = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['productTitle'] );
    $pLink          = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['productURL'] );
    $pPrice         = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['productPrice'] );
    $pShippingPrice = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['shippingPrice'] );
    $pWeight        = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['productWeight'] );
    $currency       = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['coCurrency'] );
    $productCat     = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['productCategory'] );
    $coUserID       = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['userID'] );
    $is_PhonePro    = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['is_Phone'] );
    $is_AmazonPro   = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['is_Amazon'] );
    $is_ExpressShip = wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['is_Express'] );  the product creation below


    function get_product_category_by_id( $category_id ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $category_id, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A' );
        return $term['name'];
    }
    $product_CO_terms = get_product_category_by_id( 15 );

    $post = array(
        'post_author' => $coUserID,
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_excerpt' => $pProduct_excerpt,
        'post_title' => $pTitle,
        'post_type' => "product",
    );

    //create product for product ID
    $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

    //type of product
    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'simple', 'product_type');

    //Which Category
    wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $product_CO_terms, 'product_cat' );

    //setting Shipping class
    wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, array($pShipping_Class), 'product_shipping_class' );

    //add product meta
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $productPrice_converted );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $productPrice_converted );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_weight', $pWeight );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_store_product_uri', $pLink );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_list_of_stores', 'custom-order' );

    set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, 245 );

    //get woocommerce shortcode for add to cart
    $found = false;
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                $found = true;
        }
        // if product not found, add it
        if ( ! $found )
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    } else {
        // if no products in cart, add it
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }


    /**************/
    /*****THIS IS THE PART I HAVE PROBLEM WITH*********/
    /**************/
    //get order ID
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    //grab items from the order id
    $items = $order->get_items();

    //loop thru all products in the order section and get product ID 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];

        //choose whatever suites you, trash the product is what I picked

        //permanently deletes product
        //wp_delete_post($product_id);

        //trashes post
        wp_trash_post($product_id);
    }

    /**************/
    /*****THE PART I HAVE PROBLEM WITH ENDS HERE*********/
    /**************/

    if ( $product_id > 1 )  {
        echo $product_id;
    }else {
        echo '0';
    }

    die();
}
```

but when i did it in the above way i got a lot of notice error regarding undefined variables which is used for the post creation. I think its not the right way to go about this. So i would like to check if a product belongs to the category (`$product_CO_terms` returns the ID for the category) and if the order associated to the product(s) in the category is completed, then the product should be trashed or deleted.

Thanks

Comment: Actually your code is not testable *(incomplete)*… Please remember that "*Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.*".

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the code is much, that is why I added the part I need help with while using comment to show what each doesn't and the code missing which are just variables getting values from the form submitted by user

Comment: I just want to be able to delete a product created by this code above automatically when the order attached to such product is marked as completed

Comment: Sorry but your actual code is not enough… People can't guess things by magic and that's may be why nobody answers.

Comment: Will add all the code ... Let. me do that now

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have updated the question, having all the codes